# #error Unsupported architecture - cdefs.h - Swift BLE project was working fine in Swift 2.3 but gives error in Swift 3.0 only on real device

Tags: ios, swift, architecture, device

When the project was Swift 2.3 all worked on the Simulator and my iPhone 6S
After Converting to Swift 3.0 and some improvements I receive an error **ONLY** when running on a real device... Running on the simulated works just fine.

[image: Xcode exception]

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by removing all the framework files, and added the files one at a time to find that a framework file was corrupt. replacing the file from a backup did the trick